# Calling one factory within another AngularJS Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I've written an ionic app with two factory one called Api that handles API calls and one called ldb(local database) that handles interaction with a local Sqlite database using the CordovaSqlite plugin.

When I try to use either factory separately they function as intended however when I try to use ldb within Apis functions it doesn't return data.

Here is my ldb code. Please note db is defined in the root scope as the sqlite database.

```
.factory('ldb', function($cordovaSQLite) {
  function currentSite(){
    return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"SELECT * FROM sites WHERE id=1");
  }

 return{
          current: function(){return currentSite()}
  }
}
```

and here is my api code

```
.factory('api', function($http,config,ldb) {

  function getLastEvent(){

  ldb.currentSite().this(function(res){
    var siteid = res.rows.item(0).siteid;
    var sitepin = res.rows.item(0).sitepin;

  if(siteid != null && sitepin != null){
        $scope.lastEvent = $http.post(config.apiURL, {siteid: siteid, sitepin:   sitepin, action: 'getLastEvent'});
        return true;
     }
  else{ return {"AlertType":"OP","Time":"00:00","Date":"No Site"};}
        return {"AlertType":"OP","Time":"00:00","Date":"No Site"};
    })
  }
return{
 lastEvent: function(){return getLastEvent()}
}
```

I am calling api in my controller like this.

```
app.lastEvent().then(function(res){
  if(res.data == "Invalid Details Provided!"){$scope.lastEvent = {"AlertType":"OP","Time":"Invalid Login","Date":""};}
  else if(res.data != null){ $scope.lastEvent = res.data[0];}
  else{$scope.lastEvent ={"AlertType":"OP","Time":"Error","Date":""}}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:
in 'api' factory you wrote `ldb.currentSite().this(...`
 instead of `ldb.current().then(...`.

In fact the 'ldb' factory returns a function named `current()`.

Besides, pay attention, `$cordovaSQLite.execute()` is an asynchronous operation so it returns a promise which has the method `then()` not `this()`.

Finally you said db is defined in the "root scope": what do you mean? It is a property of $rootScope? If yes you have to reference it with $rootScope.db.

Comment: to add to this list  in your ldb factory your return statement wraps the function `currentSite` inside another function. The return part can just be written as `return { current: currentSite }`... same applies to the return of the api factory